# enable password prompt when git clone (ssh)

Tags: git, gitlab, ssh-keys, git-clone, ssh-keygen

I had to clone my project from GITLAB.
I hd generated an ssh key then i added id_rsa.pub to the Gitlab ssh key on web interface of gitlab.
When i want to clone with ssh `git clone git@.....` i need to enter a password. I thinked that i should enter the password of my user session but it is wrong.
After many attempt, i can't enter the password and i got this error.

```
warning: modèles non trouvés /usr/local/share/git-core/templates/
sign_and_send_pubkey: signing failed: agent refused operation

git@site.com: Permission denied (publickey).
fatal: Impossible de lire le dépôt distant.

Veuillez vérifier que vous avez les droits d'accès
et que le dépôt existe.
```

Answer (score 1):

I resolved my problem
it was a permission problem. the id_rsa  (private key) have a permission too open.
when i run `ssh-add ./.ssh/id_rsa` this is the result

```
@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@
@         WARNING: UNPROTECTED PRIVATE KEY FILE!          @
@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@
Permissions 0644 for './.ssh/id_rsa' are too open.
It is required that your private key files are NOT accessible by others.
This private key will be ignored.
```

the private key should have this permission 600. So i run

```
chmod 600 ./.ssh/id_rsa
```

then i run again

```
ssh-add ./.ssh/id_rsa
```

then i can do git clone with ssh

Answer (score 0):

I think Git is asking for your private key password, that you chose when you generated your public/private keys.

Comment: You mean the passphrase ?

Comment: You mean the passphrase ? My problem that the window where i tape the password doesn't appear again

Comment: I believe it is asking for the passphrase once per user session. A quick way of forcing it to ask the passphrase again is just logging out from your user and logging back in again and try git clone. What OS are you using?

Comment: I'm using ubuntu 18.04. I tried to reboot my pc but it is usually the same thing. I can't enter my passphrase. the prompt window where i type the password don't appear again

Comment: I'm pretty sure there are better ways of forcing the window to show up, but you can try killing your ssh-agent. You can get the PID using "ps -aux | grep ssh-agent" and then kill the process. After that, git clone will ask you for the passphrase in the terminal. I tried this on an Ubuntu 16.04.

Comment: Thank you very much. I solved my problem. See the response